# How to generate partially repeated permutations in ruby?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, permutation

I have a range of numbers R = `(1..n)`. I also have another character `'a'`. I want to generate strings of length `L` (L > n + 2)  that have all the numbers in the same order, but go through every repeated permutation of `'a'` to fill the length L. For example, if `n = 3`, and `L = 7`, then some valid strings would be :

```
"123aaaa",
"1a23aaa",
"1aa2a3a",
"aaaa123"
```

while the following strings would be invalid:

```
"213aaaa", # invalid, because 1,2,3 are not in order
"123a", #invalid, because length < L
"1123aaa", # invalid because a number is repeated
```

I am currently doing this, which is way too inefficient:

```
n = 3
L = 7
all_terms = (1..n).to_a + Array.new(L - n, 'a')
all_terms.permutation.each do |permut|
  if(valid_permut? permut) # checks if numbers are in their natural order
    puts permut.join
  end
end
```

How do I directly generate valid strings more efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is equivalent to: select `n` elements from index `0` to `L - 1`, fill these with `1` to `n` accordingly, and fill the rest with some constant character.

In your example, it's taking `3` elements from `0..6`:

```
(0..6).to_a.combination(3).to_a
 => [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 4], [0, 1, 5], [0, 1, 6], [0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 4],
 [0, 2, 5], [0, 2, 6], [0, 3, 4], [0, 3, 5], [0, 3, 6], [0, 4, 5], [0, 4, 6], [0, 5, 6], 
 [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 6], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4, 5],
 [1, 4, 6], [1, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 6], [2, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6], [2, 5, 6],
 [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 6], [3, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Every subarray here represents a possible result. For example, `[0, 2, 3]` corresponds to `'0a12aaa'`, `[3, 5, 6]` corresponds to  `'aaa0a12'`, etc. The code for this conversion is straight-forward.

Answer (score 2):

You can model this as all possible interleavings of two strings, where relative order of the input elements is preserved. Here's a recursive solution. It works by choosing an element from one list, and prepending it to all possible subproblems, then doing it again where an element is chosen from the second list instead, and combining the two solution sets at the end.

```
# Returns an array of all possible interleaving of two strings
# Maintains relative order of each character of the input strings
def interleave_strings_all(a1, a2)
    # Handle base case where at least one input string is empty
    return [a1 + a2] if a1.empty? || a2.empty?

    # Place element of first string, and prepend to all subproblems
    set1 = interleave_strings_all(a1[1..-1], a2).map{|x| a1[0] + x}
    # Place element of second string and prepend to all subproblems
    set2 = interleave_strings_all(a1, a2[1..-1]).map{|x| a2[0] + x}

    # Combine solutions of subproblems into overall problem
    return set1.concat(set2)    
end


if __FILE__ == $0 then
    l = 5
    n = 3
    a1 = (1..n).to_a.map{|x| x.to_s}.join()
    a2 = 'a' * (l - n)
    puts interleave_strings_all(a1, a2)
end
```

The output is:

```
 123aa
 12a3a
 12aa3
 1a23a
 1a2a3
 1aa23
 a123a
 a12a3
 a1a23
 aa123
```

Comment: You can use `a1.empty?` instead of `a1.length == 0` and the method name should be in snake_case

Comment: @Stefan Ahh silly me. I forgot about `.empty?`. I've never been a fan of snake_case, but I suppose that is a fairly entrenched Ruby practice.